# Not able to update anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Getting error : "PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')" when trying to update conda, on windows 7 professional, and hence unable to install a lot of other packages like spacy, tensorflow, librosa etc.

```
(base) C:\Users\companyadmin>conda update conda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda: 4.4.10-py36_0 --> 4.6.14-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling packag
e 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Answer (score 1):

considering that system you want to install is not your personal system but belong to the company you are working for.

so the company has restricted the install of program to employee  on certian folder like c:\programdata\ or c:\program files
to install/unistall there one need to have admin permision .

so you need admin permission to install the program there, ie run the command in admin mode

how to solve this issue,

```
install/save the anaconda in seperate folder ie in some folder in system you have created
then you can update the anaconda in your system
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will try and run in administrator mode.

Comment: @Shreyashtripathi don't forgot to accept , upvote if it's works

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow, despite up voting I guess my votes are not publicly displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda update conda (ubuntu)
```

or run anaconda promt as administrator and then (for windows) :

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will try and run in administrator mode

Comment: Hey kacper, just saw your profile and seems like you are working on speech recognition, I am working on the same field, was stuck in between when I was trying to build one, can you help me on that?